# DataTables Requested unknown parameter 'PageId'

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, datatables

I am running into the following error trying to load DataTables Objects data (https://datatables.net/manual/data/):

```
DataTables warning: table id=report-table - Requested unknown parameter 'PageId' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/
```

Below is example json data I am recieving from my C# SchemaReport/GetReportJson controller and being used in JQuery ajax success callback to initialize my DataTables:

```
[{"PageId":"foo","SchemaName":"foo","Name":"foo","LastModified":"foo","LastModifiedUser":"foo"}]
```

DataTables HTML:

```
<table id="report-table" class="display nowrap" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Page ID</th>
            <th>Schema</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Last Modified</th>
            <th>Last Modified User</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Page ID</th>
            <th>Schema</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Last Modified</th>
            <th>Last Modified User</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

JQuery ajax and DataTables init script:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("button#report-form-submit").click(function () {
            event.preventDefault();
            var data = $("form#report-form").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("GetReportJson", "Report")",
                data: data,
                dataType: "json",
                beforeSend: function (data) {
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    // Report DataTables Init
                    // ===========================================
                    $('#report-table').DataTable({
                        data: data,
                        columns : [
                            {
                                data : 'PageId'
                            },
                            {
                                data : 'SchemaName'
                            },
                            {
                                data : 'Name'
                            },
                            {
                                data : 'LastModified'
                            },
                            {
                                data : 'LastModifiedUser'
                            }
                        ],
                        dom: 'Bfrtip',
                        buttons: [
                            {
                                extend: 'csv',
                                text: 'Download CSV',
                                filename: 'report-file'
                            },
                            {
                                extend: 'excel',
                                text: 'Download Excel',
                                filename: 'report-file',
                                title: ''
                            },
                        ]
                    });
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                },
                complete: function (data) {
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I noticed that after acknowledging the error DataTables loads as following and stating 134 entries:

[image]

134 matches the character count of the json data (provided in answer). For some reason it appears DataTables is not seeing the json object and parsing individual characters? Just not sure why it would be doing this?

Comment: Try to check typeof `data`. Is it returned as an array or string? If it returns as string, you need to verify whether your API is returned the JSON value in string or...

Comment: I am using JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objs) to serialize my c# objects which states it "Serializes the specified object to a JSON string." [https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/m_newtonsoft_json_jsonconvert_serializeobject.htm]. I can update question with my c# controller code if helps.

Comment: You don't need to serialize the object. If you use ASP.NET MVC, just return the data as `new JsonResult(/* data */);`. Ya, share the Controller code would be helpful =)

Comment: That was it! I very silly for overlooking that the ASP.NET MVC Controller was returning JSON string. I will post an answer with the before and after controller changes that solved issue, but you comments are the true answer and appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `columns` block should be:

```
                    columns : [
                        {
                            'data' : 'PageId'
                        },
                        {
                            'data' : 'SchemaName'
                        },
                        {
                            'data' : 'Name'
                        },
                        {
                            'data' : 'LastModified'
                        },
                        {
                            'data' : 'LastModifiedUser'
                        }
                    ],
```

You should also be sending your data from the `Controller` like this:

```
return Json(schemaData);
```

You do not need to serialize your data when you are returning a `JSON` since this will already return data in `JSON` format and if you use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` then you are converting it twice which the DataTable plugin does not like.

Comment: I was using that format originally and changed to match Data Objects example on (https://datatables.net/manual/data/). Same results on both.

Comment: @OtoNoOto Then it seems a `Controller` issue, you do not need to serialize your data when you are sending a `return Json` since this will already return a JSON and if you use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` then you are converting it twice which the DataTable plugin does not like. I have updated my answer to include this. information

Comment: This is correct! Yong Shun comments lead me to noticing that. Updated and working now! Since you updated your answer I will mark as correct answer. I will update my original Question with my before and after controller code as well for future reference. Thanks for all your help!